# CSS shadow white line at the end of linear-gradient background

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I try to build a beautiful gradient in CSS, like this one built in PhotoShop :[image]

But when I try to create one in CSS, I always get a white line at the end of the linear-gradient background :

```html
<html>
<head>

  <style>
    html, body {
      margin:  0;
      padding:  0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {

      background: transparent;  /* fallback for old browsers */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(24,54,85,1.00), transparent 25%);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(24,54,85,1.00), transparent 25%); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Ending like that :

[image: Photoshop][image: CSS with the white line]

To be fully understood : the line isn't real, it's a counter-effect of my gradient, it's a fake line ! but it is still something I want to erase.
I am sure there is something better to do in CSS, don't you ?

Comment: what line ? ...

Comment: Code above does not replicate the error you are describing - change your body background-color and you will see that whatever white line you see is not created by the gradient

Comment: Your gradient is only on 25% of body, the bottom is all white. if you want gradient to be till the end of the page without white in the bottom, place 100% on transparent

Comment: @arnaudambro - Is this more what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/8k0L5u6c/

Comment: I added a picture showing the line, I hope it's better for understanding

Comment: @user2796515 it's actually what I have been trying to do too, but the challenge is that the gradient should stop half page, not at the bottom... and that's where this white line appears.

Comment: to be fully clear : the line isn't real, it's a counter-effect of my gradient, it's a fake line ! but it is still something I want to erase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user2796515 I was able to find what felt wrong in my linear gradient : it's because there is no ease-out when it ends. Of course, it's linear, by definition...
Anyway, I knew what keywords I needed to put in Google to try and add an proper cubic-bezier to a linear-gradient, and I fell on [this article from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/easing-linear-gradients/) explaining exactly my feeling. I know can use this [postcss-easing-gradients plugin](https://github.com/larsenwork/postcss-easing-gradients), and the result is perfect for me, and fully customizable !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(24,54,85,1.00), transparent 25%);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(24,54,85,1.00), transparent 25%);
```

to

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(24,54,85,1.00), transparent 100%);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(24,54,85,1.00), transparent 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has the desired settings (half way down the page) for the gradient:

```
   background: white;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(1,1,1,.74) 1%, rgba(24,54,85,1) 13%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(1,1,1,.74)1%, rgba(24,54,85,1) 13%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(1,1,1,.74) 1%, rgba(24,54,85,1) 13%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(1,1,1,.74) 1%, rgba(24,54,85,1) 13%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
```

Please see edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8k0L5u6c/2/

Comment: it still has what looks like a white line at 50%... actually, it fills like the gradient doesn't have an ease-out, but it ends sharply, do you understand my point ?

Comment: @arnaudambro.  Not really sure I see it.  I have updated the fiddle with a solid white gradient into the white background.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual line, it is just a result of gradient background. 
you can erase it by assigning transparent border to the container having gradient background. This solution works for me every time. e.g
 
   `background: linear-gradient(110deg, #017baa 0%, #017baa 0%, #2d4f37 100%, #2d4f37 100%);
   border-top: 1px solid transparent;
   background-clip: content-box;`